# How to query "ordered" rows for all rows "after" and one "previous" efficiently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks like that:

```
Time        Id

10:00        2
11:00        1
12:00        4
12:00        3
13:00        5
```

The order is important for business logic and the order is `Time` descending, then `Id` descending. When I add/change a row I need to do a query to all rows "after" (according to a given order) and including a given row and one "previous" row.

I did not manage to figure out how to it better than 2 queries like that:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Time > @Time OR (Time = @Time AND Id >= @Id) // Get all rows after and including
SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE Time < @Time OR (Time = @Time AND Id < @Id) ORDER BY Time DESC, Id DESC // Get previous
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing the query?

Example 1:

I need to update a row with Id 3, then I need the query to return rows with ids 3,4,5 and a previous with id 1

Example 2:

I need to update a row with Id 4, then I need the query to return rows with ids 4,5 and a previous with id 3

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: *"When I add/change a row I need to do a query to all rows "after" (according to a given order) and including a given row and one "previous" row."* And do *what*?

Comment: There are a lot of other columns that I will do some processing on in the application code and then I'll update changed rows

Comment: Why not `OUTPUT` the value of `inserted.time` and `inserted.id`, and then you can `SELECT` all the rows after that time, or at the same time, and greater `id`??

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the examples, I hope that makes it a bit more clear

Comment: @Larnu Well, that's pretty much what I did in my SQL query, but to do business logic I do need one "previous" row to calculate some stuff

Comment: Though, considering you know what you're `INSERT`ing/`UPDATE`ing anyway (I assume via parameters) why not just perform a `SELECT [Time],ID FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE [Time] > @Time OR ([Time] = @Time AND ID > @ID);`?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, it's almost exactly the same as the query I did write, it's the "previous" that is a bit more tricky that I am not sure if it will perform well and if it's the correct approach, or perhaps one query that will return both things that I want

Comment: *"it's the "previous" that is a bit more tricky "* Just reverse the logic. `SELECT [Time],ID FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE [Time] < @Time OR ([Time] = @Time AND ID < @ID);`

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that's what I did, but I need only one row that is previous, so I added Select TOP 1 and then Order by. So my question really is if that is an efficient query or there is a better way?

Comment: Provided you have appropriate indexes, that query (that I provided) will be efficient.